# Unknown column 'mbr.id' in 'on clause' from php4 to php5

Tags: php, mysql, cron

We have a PHP script that send newsletters to members. It's been working OK in old server. It's not working in new server. The server log says something like this:

**SQL Error:**

```
SELECT pr.*, mbr.*, pr.id AS id2, c.name AS country_name, s.name AS state_name 

FROM capitalists as mbr, profile_cap as pr 

LEFT JOIN `sent_matched_reccords` AS sentinfo 

ON (sentinfo.rcpt_type="investors" AND sentinfo.msg_type="matched_investors" AND sentinfo.rcpt_id="11126" AND sentinfo.mbr_id=mbr.id) 

LEFT JOIN `country` AS c ON pr.country=c.id 
LEFT JOIN `state` AS s ON pr.state=s.id 
WHERE mbr.id=pr.capid AND ISNULL(sentinfo.mbr_id) AND pr.companyname != "" LIMIT 15
<br>
Unknown column 'mbr.id' in 'on clause'
<br>
```

Above is the log error. Our script that has sql command goes like this:

$db->runquery(
        'SELECT '
        .' mbr.*'
        .', pr.country as p_country'
        .', pr.state as p_state'
        .', pr.'.$members_industry_pr.' as p_industry'
        .' FROM '.$members_db.' as mbr, '.$members_pr_db.' as pr'
        .' WHERE'
        .' mbr.notify3_freq_'.$msg_type.'="'.$freq.'" AND mbr.unsubscribed = "no"'
        .' AND mbr.id=pr.'.$members_id_pr
    .'');

```
while ($db->getrow()) {
    $member = $db->getcurrentrow();

    if ($test && !in_array($member['email'], $test_emails)) {
        continue;
    };

$SQLStr = 'SELECT '
            .' pr.*'
            .', mbr.*'
            .', pr.id AS id2'
            .', c.name AS country_name'
            .', s.name AS state_name'
            .' FROM '.$list_db.' as mbr, '.$list_pr_db.' as pr'
            .' LEFT JOIN `sent_matched_reccords` AS sentinfo ON ('
                .'sentinfo.rcpt_type="'.$rcpt_type.'"'
                .' AND '
                .'sentinfo.msg_type="'.$msg_type.'"'
                .' AND '
                .'sentinfo.rcpt_id="'.$member['id'].'"'
                .' AND '
                .'sentinfo.mbr_id=mbr.id'
            .')'
            .' LEFT JOIN `country` AS c ON pr.country=c.id'
            .' LEFT JOIN `state` AS s ON pr.state=s.id'
            .' WHERE'
            .' mbr.id=pr.'.$list_id_pr
            .' AND ISNULL(sentinfo.mbr_id)'         
            .' AND pr.companyname != ""'
        .'';
```

Can anybody tells me how to fix the script? This script is sent using cron scheduling.

p.s. I am adding the following:

```
$members_db = $message_types[$rcpt_type][$msg_type]['members_db'];
$members_pr_db = $message_types[$rcpt_type][$msg_type]['members_pr_db'];
$members_id_pr = $message_types[$rcpt_type][$msg_type]['members_id_pr'];
$members_industry_pr = $message_types[$rcpt_type][$msg_type]  ['members_industry_pr'];

$list_db = $message_types[$rcpt_type][$msg_type]['list_db'];
$list_pr_db = $message_types[$rcpt_type][$msg_type]['list_pr_db'];
$list_id_pr = $message_types[$rcpt_type][$msg_type]['list_id_pr'];
$list_industry_pr = $message_types[$rcpt_type][$msg_type]['list_industry_pr'];

$template_file = $message_types[$rcpt_type][$msg_type]['template'];
$subject = $message_types[$rcpt_type][$msg_type]['subject'];
```

Comment: Please show the ddl of your tables.

Comment: definition of variable is: $members_db = $message_types[$rcpt_type][$msg_type]['members_db'];
 $members_pr_db = $message_types[$rcpt_type][$msg_type]['members_pr_db'];
 $members_id_pr = $message_types[$rcpt_type][$msg_type]['members_id_pr'];
 $members_industry_pr = $message_types[$rcpt_type][$msg_type]['members_industry_pr'];$list_db = $message_types[$rcpt_type][$msg_type]['list_db'];
 $list_pr_db = $message_types[$rcpt_type][$msg_type]['list_pr_db'];
 $list_id_pr = $message_types[$rcpt_type][$msg_type]['list_id_pr'];

Comment: $list_industry_pr = $message_types[$rcpt_type][$msg_type]['list_industry_pr'];

 $template_file = $message_types[$rcpt_type][$msg_type]['template'];
 $subject = $message_types[$rcpt_type][$msg_type]['subject'];

Comment: Plaese add it to your question using the edit function. Not as a comment.

Comment: Oww... please edit code in your question and format it. In a comment it is barely legible. And as Jens stated, please show the definition of your tables.

Comment: Hi, this is the line before the code. Is this what you mean by 'definition of tables"?$db->runquery(
  'SELECT '
  .' mbr.*'
  .', pr.country as p_country'
  .', pr.state as p_state'
  .', pr.'.$members_industry_pr.' as p_industry'
  .' FROM '.$members_db.' as mbr, '.$members_pr_db.' as pr'
  .' WHERE'
  .' mbr.notify3_freq_'.$msg_type.'="'.$freq.'" AND mbr.unsubscribed = "no"'
  .' AND mbr.id=pr.'.$members_id_pr
 .'');

 while ($db->getrow()) {
  $member = $db->getcurrentrow();

  if ($test && !in_array($member['email'], $test_emails)) {
   continue;
  };

Comment: hi I edit and add some codes in question. Is that what you mean by DDL?